# How to access canonical URL in Next.js with Automatic Static Optimization turned on?

Tags: next.js

I'm working on SEO component which needs a canonical URL.

How can I get URL of static page in Next.js with Automatic Static Optimization turned on?

Answer (score 16):

Using `useRouter` from `next/router` you can get the `pathname` for the current page and use it in a `<Head/>` tag as following:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const site = "https://gourav.io";
const canonicalURL = site + useRouter().pathname;

<Head>
  <link rel="canonical" href={canonicalURL} />
</Head>
```

Comment: You might prefer to use `useRouter().asPath`, which will work even for [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes).

`pathname` will show up as `"/posts/[pid]"` whereas `asPath` will show up as `"/posts/my-post-id"` which is what you want for real URLs.

Comment: @fzembow there's one more difference. `useRouter().pathname` returns the path excluding any query parameters (blog/first-blog) whereas `useRouter().asPath` returns the complete path including hashes etc for ex: blog/first-blog#some-heading

Answer (score 10):

Building on [fzembow's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61574405/how-to-access-canonical-url-in-next-js-with-automatic-static-optimization-turned#comment118975770_65078853) about `useRouter().asPath` and [GorvGoyl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65078853/2738164), here's an implementation which manages to handle both dynamic routes and excludes anchor and query param URL extensions:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const CANONICAL_DOMAIN = 'https://yoursite.com';

const router = useRouter();
const _pathSliceLength = Math.min.apply(Math, [
    router.asPath.indexOf('?') > 0 ? router.asPath.indexOf('?') : router.asPath.length,
    router.asPath.indexOf('#') > 0 ? router.asPath.indexOf('#') : router.asPath.length
]);
const canonicalURL= CANONICAL_DOMAIN + router.asPath.substring(0, _pathSliceLength);

<Head>
  <link rel="canonical" href={ canonicalURL } />
</Head>
```

Answer (score 0):

use package called next-absolute-url . It works in getServerSideProps. Since getStaticProps run on build time so dont have data available.
can be used as

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
 const { req, query } = ctx;
   const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);      
      return {
        props: {
          canonicalUrl: `${origin}/user-listings`,
        },
      };
    };

export const getStaticProps:GetStaticProps = async (ctx) => {
  return {
    props: {
      canonicalUrl: 'https://www.test.com',
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A super ugly, yet, the most adequate solution I found:

```js
const canonicalUrl = typeof window === 'undefined' ?
  '' :
  `${window.location.origin}/${window.location.pathname}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use new URL with router.asPath.

```
    const CURRENT_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CURRENT_SITE_URL

    const getCanonical = (path: string) => {
      const fullURL = new URL(path, CURRENT_URL)
      return`${fullURL.origin}${fullURL.pathname}
    }

    export const Page = () => {
      const router = useRouter()
      const canonical = getCanonical(router.asPath)

      <Head>
        <link rel="canonical" href={canonical} />
      </Head>
      <div>
      ...
      <div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a canonical link tag to `_app.js` so that it appears on every page:

```
<link
   rel="canonical"
   href={typeof window !== 'undefined' && `${window.location.origin}${useRouter().asPath}`}
   key="canonical"
/>
```